# SharePoint App link

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-addin, access

I am coding a web app that will list all SharePoint apps available for one user.

How is it possible to know if a user is allowed or not to access a SharePoint app? It is useless to display a link if the user doesn't have the right permissions.

Is it possible to do something with NTLM login? The different SharePoint apps are on different domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming here that the App has deployed an App Web you could check the EffectiveBasePermissions.

Something like

```
context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = context.get_web();
this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
context.load(this._currentUser);
context.load(web,'EffectiveBasePermissions');
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));
}
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) 
{
  if (web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems)) 
  {
     //User Has Edit Permissions
  }
}}
```

Code courtesy of MSDN answer:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/f21ad6b1-445a-497d-a286-d3ba8c2928a6/how-to-get-the-current-user-permission-level-on-a-list-item-with-ecmascript

**EDIT**
To run across different version you might want to look at using the server object model.  The below will iterate over a web and list out all lists and users with access. You can modify this to check for a specific user and return that results.  the roleassignment method is what you will want to work with.  Hope this works a little better for you.

This is from StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248211/getting-all-sites-lists-and-user-permissions-in-sharepoint

```
static void ListLists()
        {
            SPWebApplication webApp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://mossdev:8060"));
            foreach(SPSite site in webApp.Sites)
            {
                try
                {
                    PrintWebAndListsRecursive(site.RootWeb, 0);
                }
                finally
                {
                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PrintWebAndListsRecursive(SPWeb web, int level)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(level * 3) + "Site: {0} ({1})", web.Title, web.Url);
            foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft((level + 1) * 3) + "List: {0}", list.Title);
                foreach(SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in list.RoleAssignments)
                {                    
                    if(roleAssignment.Member is SPGroup)
                    {
                        var group = (SPGroup) roleAssignment.Member;
                        Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft((level + 2) * 3) + "Group: {0}", group.Name);   
                        foreach(SPUser user in group.Users)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft((level + 4) * 3) + user.Name);   
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft((level + 2) *3) + "User: {0}", roleAssignment.Member.Name);  
                    }

                    foreach(SPRoleDefinition roleDef in roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                    {
                        if (!roleDef.Hidden)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft((level + 3) * 3) + "Role Definition: {0}", roleDef.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach(SPWeb subWeb in web.Webs)
            {
                try
                {
                    PrintWebAndListsRecursive(subWeb, level+1);
                }
                finally
                {
                    subWeb.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok it works with sharepoint 2013 appz but what about sharepoint 2007 appz ?

Comment: You will need to clarify on what you mean by 2007 appz?  2007 didn't have what we call Apps.  in 2007 you could deploy full trust code in WSP packages - which could contain, literally anything.  It might extend a site or it might be a site.

Comment: Sorry by "appz" I was meaning sharepoint websites. Your solution is working with new sharepoint websites but it is not working with the old ones. Also I don't need to know in details the permissions of one user, I just need to know if he can access or not the website. With your solution when the user cannot access the website, there is a windows authentification pop up showing up when I am firing "executeQueryAsync", this is also a problem.